Tailscale SSH with VSCode: Permission Denied
I've set up a Tailscale network with two nodes, one tagged tag:server, the other tagged as tag:client. Server is an Ubuntu 22.04 machine, and the client is a Windows laptop. I want to access my server using VSCode's Remote SSH plugin but I repeatedly receive a Permission Denied error. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix the SSH permissions?
My ACL is as follows:
{
    "groups": {
        "group:admin": [<my_email_address>],
    },
    "tagOwners": {
        "tag:server": ["group:admin"],
        "tag:client": ["group:admin"],
    },
    "acls": [
        {"action": "accept", "src": ["*"], "dst": ["*:*"]},
    ],

    "ssh": [
        {
            "action": "accept",
            "src":    ["group:admin"],
            "dst":    ["tag:server"],
            "users":  ["autogroup:nonroot"],
        },
    ],
    "nodeAttrs": [
        {
            "target": ["tag:server"],
            "attr":   ["funnel"],
        },
    ],
}


My SSH config is as follows:
Host homeserver
    User <non_root_username>
    HostName homeserver.<my_tailnet_id>.ts.net

I've tried SSH via the Admin Console (which works fine). SSH via CMD.exe, VSCode Remote, and VSCode Tailscale extension all fail with a Permission Denied error with no context about why.
Edit:
Attempted SSH with -vvv. The logs are below:
C:\Users\this_user>ssh -vvv username@homeserver.<my_tailnet>.ts.net
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\this_user/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\this_user/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for homeserver.<my_tailnet>.ts.net
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\this_user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\this_user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug2: resolving "homeserver.<my_tailnet>.ts.nett" port 22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to homeserver.<my_tailnet>.ts.net [100.110.num.num] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10013, io:000002B367DC5260
debug1: connect to address 100.110.num.num port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host homeserver.<my_tailnet>.ts.net port 22: Permission denied

The ssh config error is a false flag, since there's an ssh config in Users/this_user/.ssh where the actual configuration is stored.

To get more about the failure you should try ssh -vvv homeserver
